# Computed key, as interface key, from enum member

Tags: typescript, enums, interface

I am trying to set up an object property by selecting its key using a computed key, through an enum, like in the following snippet of code.

For some reason, solution 1, and 2 don't work. Those are the solutions I'd like to use in my code, since I need to assign a value to a key that's dynamically obtained from an API call.

What's weird, in my ignorance, is that solutions 4 and 5 are working, demonstrating that, actually, also solutions 1 and 2 could "potentially" work, by reassigning property values with the dynamic key, following hard-coded property key.

That's of course because TypeScript, as long as you provide matching interface properties, accepts an arbitrary number of additional properties, but, still, I don't understand why duplicated, dynamic properties, are working in 4 and 5.

**That said, why solution 1 and 2 are not working? What am I doing wrong?**

Thanks for your help.

```js
interface Cat {
    tail: boolean;
    legs: Quadruped;
}

interface Quadruped {
    totalNumber: number;
}

enum BodyParts {
    TAIL = 'tail',
    TOTAL_NUMBER = 'totalNumber'
}

let brokenArgo: Cat = { tail: true, legs: { totalNumber: 4 } };
let argo: Cat = { tail: true, legs: { totalNumber: 4 } };

argo.legs = null;

let TN = 'TOTAL_NUMBER';
let tn: BodyParts = BodyParts[TN];

// solution 1 = broken
brokenArgo.legs = { [tn]: 6 }
// solution 2 = broken
brokenArgo.legs = { [BodyParts[TN]]: 6 };
// solution 3 = working
argo.legs = { [BodyParts['TOTAL_NUMBER']]: 6 };
// solution 4 = working
argo.legs = {
    totalNumber: 0,
    [tn]: 6
};
// solution 5 = working
argo.legs = {
    totalNumber: 0,
    [BodyParts[TN]]: 6
};
```

You can see the above script running in [Typescript playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Cat%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20tail%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20legs%3A%20Quadruped%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Quadruped%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20totalNumber%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aenum%20BodyParts%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20TAIL%20%3D%20'tail'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20TOTAL_NUMBER%20%3D%20'totalNumber'%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20brokenArgo%3A%20Cat%20%3D%20%7B%20tail%3A%20true%2C%20legs%3A%20%7B%20totalNumber%3A%204%20%7D%20%7D%3B%0D%0Alet%20argo%3A%20Cat%20%3D%20%7B%20tail%3A%20true%2C%20legs%3A%20%7B%20totalNumber%3A%204%20%7D%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aargo.legs%20%3D%20null%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20TN%20%3D%20'TOTAL_NUMBER'%3B%0D%0Alet%20tn%3A%20BodyParts%20%3D%20BodyParts%5BTN%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20solution%201%20%3D%20broken%0D%0AbrokenArgo.legs%20%3D%20%7B%20%5Btn%5D%3A%206%20%7D%0D%0A%2F%2F%20solution%202%20%3D%20broken%0D%0AbrokenArgo.legs%20%3D%20%7B%20%5BBodyParts%5BTN%5D%5D%3A%206%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20solution%203%20%3D%20working%0D%0Aargo.legs%20%3D%20%7B%20%5BBodyParts%5B'TOTAL_NUMBER'%5D%5D%3A%206%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20solution%204%20%3D%20working%0D%0Aargo.legs%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20totalNumber%3A%200%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Btn%5D%3A%206%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20solution%205%20%3D%20working%0D%0Aargo.legs%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20totalNumber%3A%200%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BBodyParts%5BTN%5D%5D%3A%206%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A)

Comment: Is the problem just that `TN` is inferred to be of type `string` instead of type `TOTAL_NUMBER`?  If so, then try `const TN = 'TOTAL_NUMBER'` (instead of `let`).

Comment: When you are declaring variable with let typescript infer its type to its primitive because it can be changed anytime and primitive type is only thing which is important. When you declare variable as const there is no need to get primitive type. It is taken as it is and type of variable is literal type equal to variable value.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This is kind of pseudo code. In real code I am assigning the variable to a Class member like in:
`classMember: enum;` and then `this.classMember = Enum.ELEMENT`
Finally, I try to use it in the object property assignment like so:
`myObject = { [this.classMember]: value }`.
I tried to change it to a const in the Playground and it actually works. How do I get the same behaviour in the class?
Thanks again for the explanation!

Comment: Declare the class property `readonly`?

Comment: @jcalz thanks for the suggestion, once read your previous comments, I thought about it and tried but, since I am assigning the value through an `@Input()` in Angular, and since I have look for changes I am using a setter so I can't use it.
As you know, I can only assign a value to readonly members in constructors.

Answer (score 0):

After some TypeScript unofficial documentation, I realized that since the interfaces declared are expecting a specific property (I.E. the interface is not optionial), I need to let TypeScript know that I am actually using a computed key "as" the expected property.
I.E. I am sure (I expect) to get from backend exactly that property.

The above (very bad example, I am sorry) can be fixed like so:

(see [live code here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Cat%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20tail%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20legs%3A%20Quadruped%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Quadruped%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20totalNumber%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aenum%20BodyParts%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20TAIL%20%3D%20'tail'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20TOTAL_NUMBER%20%3D%20'totalNumber'%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20brokenArgo%3A%20Cat%20%3D%20%7B%20tail%3A%20true%2C%20legs%3A%20%7B%20totalNumber%3A%204%20%7D%20%7D%3B%0D%0Alet%20argo%3A%20Cat%20%3D%20%7B%20tail%3A%20true%2C%20legs%3A%20%7B%20totalNumber%3A%204%20%7D%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aargo.legs%20%3D%20null%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20TN%20%3D%20'TOTAL_NUMBER'%3B%0D%0Alet%20tn%3A%20BodyParts.TOTAL_NUMBER%20%3D%20BodyParts%5BTN%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20solution%201%20%3D%20broken%0D%0AbrokenArgo.legs%20%3D%20%7B%20%5Btn%5D%3A%206%20%7D%0D%0A%2F%2F%20solution%202%20%3D%20broken%0D%0AbrokenArgo.legs%20%3D%20%7B%20%5BBodyParts%5BTN%20as%20'TOTAL_NUMBER'%5D%5D%3A%206%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20solution%203%20%3D%20working%0D%0Aargo.legs%20%3D%20%7B%20%5BBodyParts%5B'TOTAL_NUMBER'%5D%5D%3A%206%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20solution%204%20%3D%20working%0D%0Aargo.legs%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20totalNumber%3A%200%2C%20%2F%2F%20No%20more%20needed%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Btn%5D%3A%206%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20solution%205%20%3D%20working%0D%0Aargo.legs%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20totalNumber%3A%200%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BBodyParts%5BTN%5D%5D%3A%206%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A))

```js
interface Cat {
    tail: boolean;
    legs: Quadruped;
}

interface Quadruped {
    totalNumber: number;
}

enum BodyParts {
    TAIL = 'tail',
    TOTAL_NUMBER = 'totalNumber'
}

let brokenArgo: Cat = { tail: true, legs: { totalNumber: 4 } };
let argo: Cat = { tail: true, legs: { totalNumber: 4 } };

argo.legs = null;

let TN = 'TOTAL_NUMBER';
let tn: BodyParts.TOTAL_NUMBER = BodyParts[TN];

// solution 1 = broken
brokenArgo.legs = { [tn]: 6 }
// solution 2 = broken
brokenArgo.legs = { [BodyParts[TN as 'TOTAL_NUMBER']]: 6 };
// solution 3 = working
argo.legs = { [BodyParts['TOTAL_NUMBER']]: 6 };
// solution 4 = working
argo.legs = {
    // totalNumber: 0, // No more needed
    [tn]: 6
};
// solution 5 = working
argo.legs = {
    totalNumber: 0,
    [BodyParts[TN]]: 6
};
```

So, if you don't know, in advance, if you'll receive `propertyA` or `propertyB` from backend (which was my original problem), and you'd like to use a computed key then, you probably need or to set key in interface declaration as optional, or to set it up to an alias type (or an enum) like `type myType = 'propertyA' | 'propertyB'` and, then, using it as the key of the property in your interface like:

```js
interface MyInterface { 
    myType: number 
}
```